# jQuery change property of a hover class

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change my Hover-Background-Color?

```
   <style>
      .myhoverclass {background:#FFF;}
   </style>
```

I toggle with this code:

```
   $('.box a').hover(
        function(){ $(this).toggleClass('myhoverclass') }
   )
```

But when I change .myhoverclass with ColorPicker...

```
  $('#li-a-bgcolor').ColorPicker({
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#li-a-bgcolor').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        $('.myhoverclass').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
    }
  });
```

... the color stills white. Where is the mistake?

Thank You.

Comment: Make sure your `.css()` function has `backgroundColor` and not `background-color` - was this just a typo on here? (although both should work??)

Comment: Your problem is in your thinking. You are thinking you can change the definition of `.myhoverclass` when actually you are changing the `.box a` element's background-color when they have the class `.myhoverclass` attached. See my updated answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I understand correctly, you are trying to pick a color and change the hover color. The problem is you are wanting to change the class definition/rule for `.myhoverclass {background:#FFF;}` and that is a very difficult thing to do.

Instead I suggest a solution like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k6kp1e5n/

**HTML**

```
<div id="colorPicker">
     <div style="background-color: #0000FF"></div>
     <input type="text" value="#0000FF">
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#">Hover me</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#colorPicker').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000FF',
    onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorPicker div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        $('#colorPicker input').val('#' + hex);
    }
});

// Handles "hovering"
$('.box a').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $(this).css('background-color', $('#colorPicker input').val());
});
$('.box a').on('mouseout', function(e){
   $(this).css('background-color','#FFF');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.box {background:#FFF;}
```

Comment: Yes, this was the right idea. Thank you very much! I'm happy!

Answer (score 0):

Make it as simple as this. Create two classes and define colors for each classes. When ever you hover and mouseout, add and remove the classes.